# this value of a constructor inside a constructor

Tags: javascript

I thought I was getting a handle on how `this` works, but a couple of lines of code in this example have confused me a little:

```
function Bar(who) { 
    Foo.call( this, who );
}
```

I have a reasonable understanding of what `call()` does, but I can't get my head around why it is necessary in this exact example. Why does the following code not work?

```
function Bar(who) { 
    Foo( who );
}
```

Is `Foo`'s call-site not still within `Bar`, and therefore `this` will be the object created by the `new` call?

Full code:

```
function Foo(who) {
    this.me = who;
}

Foo.prototype.identify = function() {
    return "I am " + this.me;
};

function Bar(who) {
    Foo.call( this, who ); 
}

Bar.prototype = Object.create( Foo.prototype ); 

Bar.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
};

var b1 = new Bar( "b1" );
var b2 = new Bar( "b2" );

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

Thank you for any light you can shed on this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function "normally", i.e. `foo()`, then `this` inside the function will refer to the global object (or `undefined` in strict mode).

> Is `Foo`'s call-site not still within `Bar`, and therefore this will be the object created by the new call?

The value of `this` does not (implicitly) depend on where the function is called.

From [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

> ### Function context
>
> Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
>
> #### Simple call
>
> ```
> function f1(){
>    return this;
> }
> f1() === window; // global object
> ```
>
> In this case, the value of `this` is not set by the call. Since the code is not in strict mode, the value of `this` must always be an object so it defaults to the global object.

Comment: Ah, is this always the case even if that function is nested inside another function?

Comment: Yes. Context does not matter. There are only 4 ways of calling a function (all listed in the MDN documentation), which determine the value of `this`. I think it's a lot easier than people think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` value can become pretty complicated but there is a really simple rule:

### Through an object

If you call the function through another object, the object will be the this:

```
something.doIt()
```

`something` will be the `this` value, even if there is some other object leading to the object before the function.

### Just by itself

```
doIt()
```

As there is no object before the function call, the `this` will be the global object (window in browsers) or it will be `null` in case you use "use strict";

### Using new

There is another rule. If you call the function using the `new` operator, the `this` value will be the newly created object.

```
new something.MyFunction()
```

Will have the newly created object's `this` **not** `something`. In case you have/want a function call before you call the real constructor, like CommonJS module loading, you need to wrap the first part in parentheses.

```
new (require("./MyClass"))();
```

### Call and apply (and bind)

The `call`, `apply` and `bind` functions are used to overwrite the implicit `this` value.

Comment: Ah, I became confused as I thought that this would be implied with new. So, 

var b1 = new Bar( "b1" ); 

implies b1.Foo

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer to also have the `new` case.